# How can $(this) be available globally

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, this, local-variables

In JQuery, it seems that $(this) only works locally.

give a quick example:

```
$(".someClass .type1").click(function(){
    $(".someClass .type1").html("<img src='image/2.png'>");
    $(this).html("<img src='images/img.png'>");
});

$(".otherClasses").click(function(){
    $(".otherClasses .type1").html("<img src='image/2.png'>");
    $(this).html("<img src='images/img.png'>");
});
```

Ideally, I want to write a function like this:

```
function changeImg () {
   $(this).html("<img src='images/img.png'>");
}
```

And then call changeImg() under the jquery click functions like:

```
$(".someClass .type1").click(function(){
        $(".someClass .type1").html("<img src='image/2.png'>");
        changeImg();
});
```

However, in this way, the $(this) will be 'undefined' instead of the one that is clicked anymore. Is there a way to make it available like a global variable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `this` as a parameter to your functions:

```
function changeImg (el) {
   $(el).html("<img src='images/img.png'>");
}

$(".someClass .type1").click(function(){
        $(".someClass .type1").html("<img src='image/2.png'>");
        changeImg(this);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this to set the context:

```
changeImg.call(this);
```

See [MDN for `Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 changeImg(this); // pass this here
```

you code becomes

```
$(".someClass .type1").click(function(){
            $(".someClass .type1").html("<img src='image/2.png'>");
            changeImg(this); // pass this here 
    });
function changeImg (elem) {
   $(elem).html("<img src='images/img.png'>");
}
```